Getting heap storage with proper alignment in C++ for non-overaligned type
In some use case, you'll need to allocate storage before creating objects inside this storage.
Then in order to create these objects, you may need to use placement new:
T *pobj = new(pstorage);

yet you have to provide a properly aligned pstorage.
I don't understand the expected behavior of operator new:
// heap storage to hold N contiguous T objects, how to get proper alignment?
unsigned char *storage = new unsigned char[N*sizeof(T)];

Is the new expression guaranteed to return a pointer to an address suitably aligned for any "non-overaligned" type?
Does in not implies some memory fragmentation (in case of successive calls of new for weak aligned types)?

There are three types of alignment in C++: fundamental, extended, and new-extended [basic.align]. An over-aligned type is one with extended alignment, but the relevant alignment for operator new is actually new-extended.

Is the new expression guaranteed to return a pointer to an address suitably aligned for any "non-overaligned" type

operator new is guaranteed to return a pointer suitably aligned for any type which does not have new-extended alignment and is of the requested size.

Thanks but I spoke about new expression not operator new (which may be called by new expression). Thus I think that, though interesting (it shows that the question does not restrict to over-aligned types), your answer is not complete. Digging on your link, I'm finding that a new-extend alignment type is a type whose alignment is > __STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__ but is there a relationship between __STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__ and alignof(std::maxalign_t)?

I think that the definite accurate generic answer is:
unsigned char *storage = new unsigned char[N]; is always suitably aligned for types T with fundamental alignment, provided that N>=sizeof(T)
(T could also be an array by the way).
NB: at the time of this answer, cppreference misses the fundamental wording (see Allocation section).
Here are the references (at least for C++20 but it should be easy to check that it's the same for other standard versions).
expr.new

When a new-expression calls an allocation function and that allocation has not been extended, the new-expression passes the amount of space requested to the allocation function as the first argument of type std​::​size_­t. That argument shall be no less than the size of the object being created; it may be greater than the size of the object being created only if the object is an array and the allocation function is not a non-allocating form ([new.delete.placement]). For arrays of char, unsigned char, and std​::​byte, the difference between the result of the new-expression and the address returned by the allocation function shall be an integral multiple of the strictest fundamental alignment requirement of any object type whose size is no greater than the size of the array being created. [ Note: Because allocation functions are assumed to return pointers to storage that is appropriately aligned for objects of any type with fundamental alignment, this constraint on array allocation overhead permits the common idiom of allocating character arrays into which objects of other types will later be placed. — end note ]

(emphasized mine)
Be aware that it's a kind of special case for (unsigned) char and std::byte in order to allow object creation on preexisting storage.
basic.align defines alignment and alignment categories, especially:

A fundamental alignment is represented by an alignment less than or equal to the greatest alignment supported by the implementation in all contexts, which is equal to alignof(std​::​max_­align_­t) ([support.types]). The alignment required for a type might be different when it is used as the type of a complete object and when it is used as the type of a subobject.

So a type Thas fundamental alignment if and only if alignof(T)<=alignof(std::max_align_t). Overwise, it is an over-aligned type. The wording can also be type with extended-alignment.
Thus, successive bytes array allocations may lead to unused memory location between them but the fact that it matters or not is application and implementation dependent.

Eventually, for completeness sake, the standard (same ref) mentions new-extended type:

A new-extended alignment is represented by an alignment greater than STDCPP_­DEFAULT_­NEW_­ALIGNMENT
So a type T is new-extended type if and only if alignof(T)>__STDCPP_­DEFAULT_­NEW_­ALIGNMENT__.

But it should not be a concern for developers. It only gives a constraint on expression-new implementation that should select a given new operator with respect to the type being new-extended or not.
